# How to declare variables and get output as a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I work on PostgreSQL replica mode.
I run a function and place global variables in it.

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _counter int := 0;
   _size varchar;
BEGIN
   WHILE _counter <= (select  max(id) from public.customers where country='USA' )
   LOOP
      _counter := _counter + 1;
      _size= (select size from public.function_calculate_size (_counter,'type_by_country'));
   RAISE NOTICE 'The result is %, %',_counter, _size;
   END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

As a result, I get NOTICE output in the message tab.

[image]

When I try to replace  "RAISE NOTICE"  to " Select", so I get the error in the output.

Is it possible to get a result as a table and not as a message?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No need fo PL/pgSQL, variables or a loop:

```
select id, function_calculate_size(id,'type_by_country') as size
from customers 
where country='USA'
```

This is slightly different to your loop as it will only use IDs actually present in the table customers. Your simply uses all values from 0 to max(id) which could mean that it calls `function_calculate_size()` with IDs that don't actually exists in the table customers.

Comment: Hi a_horse_with_no_name.  The problem is that if I write a standard query the runtime will be 2.5 minutes compared to 20 seconds with the placement of the variables and a loop.

I understand that it is optimal to use a "for" loop and not a "while" loop. But I do not know how to do it and at the moment I am just checking if it is at all possible to get a result as a table and not as a message.

Comment: @gross if this answer takes 150s compared to 20s for a loop, then there is some other problem. You should find and treat that problem, not avoid and ignore it. Is this a table or a view? Is `id` unique? How many rows are there, and how many unique `id`s are there? Have you looked at the explain plan for this answer? Is the table being written to regularly, causing locks?

Comment: @Gross: I highly doubt that a loop is faster than a plain SQL query  There must be something else you are not telling us.

Comment: Customer is a table with a unique customer_id. The function "function_calculate_size"  uses in the calculation of the other 5 tables as well.
A single function runtime = 500 msec
700 runs in query  = 2.5 min
loop runs by 700 id's = 20 second

Comment: @Gross: again: there must be something you are not telling us. The function doesn't magically run 15 times faster just because you are calling it differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a log table and log those values like below. Log table may have below structure -

```
create table mylog (id int, logdate date, func_counter int, func_size char(50))
```

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _counter int := 0;
   _size varchar;
BEGIN
   WHILE _counter <= (select  max(id) from public.customers where country='USA' )
   LOOP
      _counter := _counter + 1;
      _size= (select size from public.function_calculate_size (_counter,'type_by_country'));
   RAISE NOTICE 'The result is %, %',_counter, _size;
   insert into mylog(func_counter, func_size) values (_counter, _size);
   END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, I can not create new tables in the database.  Just every time when  I run a script  I need to get a result in tabular form and not in print or message form.

Comment: @gross then use a temporary table ; https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

Comment: Unfortunately in  PostgreSQL replica mode, no way to create a temporary table.